# atexit not writing to file

Tags: python, atexit

I'm testing to see if the `atexit` module runs properly by attempting to print to file. The actual purpose of `atexit` will be to close the open port, however this is to test if `atexit` is working in the first place. However, `atexit` is not printing to file, any ideas why not? Any help is appreciated.

```
import atexit
import scala5
from scala5 import sharedvars
scalavars = sharedvars()
import serial
myPort=serial.Serial()

myPort.baudrate = 9600
myPort.port = "COM4"
myPort.parity=serial.PARITY_NONE
myPort.stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE
myPort.bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
myPort.timeout=2
myPort.writeTimeout=2

try:
    myPort.close()
except:
    print("didn't need to close")

def port_exit():
    fo = open("test.txt", "w")
    fo.write("This works!")
    fo.close()

myPort.open()

while True:
    x = myPort.readline()
    if x == "1\r\n":
        scalavars.door = x
    scala5.ScalaPlayer.Sleep(10)

atexit.register(port_exit)
port_exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are registering the function after your while loop, which I am assuming you are exiting by killing the script (meaning the function `port_exit` isn't registered). If you register the function before the while then it should trigger and write the file when the script exits.

```
atexit.register(port_exit)

while True:
    x = myPort.readline()
    if x == "1\r\n":
        scalavars.door = x
    scala5.ScalaPlayer.Sleep(10)
```